# Change HTTP response status code 200 - 206

Tags: apache-2.2

I was trying to redirect the users to see a default image instead of a missing image. In addition to this, I wanted to try if I could change 200 HTTP response status code to 206 and still show the default image.
I tried RewriteRule with [R=206,L] but it's showing an HTML document pertaining to 206 response.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes to the first one, no to the second one.  A 206 response can only be sent when partial content is being sent in response to a `Range` request.  I'm wondering why you'd want to do this?

Anyway, the image thing is doable - put this in a `<Directory>` block for your docroot.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|gif|png)$ [NC] # Add any other image filetypes you need
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ default_image.jpg [L]
```

Comment: I have done that but my problem is to force apache to throw 206 but still show the default image. It seems that this is a limitation of apache web server. Apache sends out html documents, saying what happened to the HTTP request.

Comment: Sending a 206 is not allowed.  You cannot send it when responding to a non-partial request.  Can you explain why you would want to send a 206?